GitLab on GCP: Cloud Build service account or user-specified service account does not have access to the bucket
We have a CD pipeline on GitLab that connects to GCP.
Starting this week we are encountering the following error (the pipeline has been used for a year now, so this is quite sudden):
Failed to create cloud build: invalid bucket "staging.app-name.appspot.com"; default Cloud Build service account or user-specified service account does not have access to the bucket

Error: Error waiting to create StandardAppVersion: Error waiting for Creating StandardAppVersion: Error code 13, message: Failed to create cloud build: invalid bucket "staging.app-name.appspot.com"; default Cloud Build service account or user-specified service account does not have access to the bucket
│ com.google.net.rpc3.client.RpcClientException: <eye3 title='/ArgoAdminNoCloudAudit.CreateBuild, FAILED_PRECONDITION'/> APPLICATION_ERROR;google.devtools.cloudbuild.v1/ArgoAdminNoCloudAudit.CreateBuild;invalid bucket "staging.app-name.appspot.com"; default Cloud Build service account or user-specified service account does not have access to the bucket;AppErrorCode=9;StartTimeMs=1715936472431;unknown;ResFormat=uncompressed;ServerTimeSec=1.005573011;LogBytes=256;Non-FailFast;EndUserCredsRequested;EffSecLevel=none;ReqFormat=uncompressed;ReqID=b1b6321e03c03d53;GlobalID=0;Server=[2002:a05:66b4:4786:b0:4:a379:3cb]:4001.

The authenticated service account is:
"serviceAccount:gitlab-ci-service-account@our-organisation.iam.gserviceaccount.com"

As this looks like an IAM issue I went to the Cloud storage bucket and added some privileges where the result of gsutil iam get gs://staging.app-name.appspot.com now looks like this:
{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "members": [
        "projectEditor:company-name-internal-dev",
        "projectOwner:company-name-internal-dev"
      ],
      "role": "roles/storage.legacyBucketOwner"
    },
    {
      "members": [
        "projectViewer:company-name-internal-dev"
      ],
      "role": "roles/storage.legacyBucketReader"
    },
    {
      "members": [
        "serviceAccount:XXXXXXXXXXX@cloudbuild.gserviceaccount.com",
        "serviceAccount:gitlab-ci-service-account@project-name.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
      ],
      "role": "roles/storage.objectViewer"
    }
  ],
  "etag": "CAM="
}

We also already enabled the Compute Engine API as per gcloud.app.deploy Error Response: [13] default Cloud Build service account or user-specified service account does not have access to the bucket

Have you checked this thread, did it help you to resolve your issue.

there is a compute service account and I dont know how the CLOUD_LOGGING_ONLY option should help resolve this

Might be useful info: The build is happening via terraform apply

I am not sure what happened, however gcp seems to be performing some changes on the default cloud build service account (https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/cloud-build-service-account).
I could not find it in our IAM console and neither could I find a mention of it when running:
gcloud projects get-iam-policy PROJECT_ID

However once I added a default cloud build service account:
gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding PROJECT_ID --member="serviceAccount:PROJECT_NUMBER@cloudbuild.gserviceaccount.com" --role="roles/cloudbuild.builds.builder"

My deployment works again.
This binding must be present in the end:
bindings:
- members:
  - serviceAccount:PROJECT_NUMBER@cloudbuild.gserviceaccount.com
  role: roles/cloudbuild.builds.builder
version: 1

